# ORA-00907: "missing right parenthesis"

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table

First of all, I apologize for asking the same question again but the information on the old topics did not work in my oraclesql code and secondly there may be some syntax errors, I learned mysql in school last semester, but now we are learning oraclesql with old mysql information in the lesson, so i am a bit confused.

So my question is i want to create 3 related table (movie-casts-actor) but i am getting missing right parenthesis. trying to connect casts table to movie table with foreign key and actor table to casts table. what am i doing wrong? how spagetti is it?

```
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    movie_id NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,
    movie_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    movie_director varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    movie_year INT(4) NOT NULL ,
    movie_duration INT(3) ,
    movie_language varchar2(15) ,
    movie_rating number(4,2) , 
    PRIMARY KEY(movie_id),
    CONSTRAINT is_unique UNIQUE(movie_id),
    CONSTRAINT movie_id_checker CHECK(movie_id>0 and movie_id<=9999999)
);

CREATE TABLE Casts (
    movie_id_fk INT(7) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Movie(movie_id) ,
    
    cast_id INT(7) NOT NULL, 
    actor_fullname varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    actor_role varchar2(50) ,
    PRIMARY KEY(cast_id),
    CONSTRAINT is_unique UNIQUE(cast_id),
    CONSTRAINT cast_id_checker CHECK(cast_id>0 and cast_id<=9999999)
);

CREATE TABLE Actor (
    cast_id_fk INT(7) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Casts(cast_id) ,
    
    actor_id INT(7) NOT NULL,
    actor_name CHAR(30) ,
    actor_surname CHAR(25) ,
    actor_gender CHAR(5) ,
    actor_age CHAR(3) CONSTRAINT real_age_check CHECK(actor_age>0 AND actor_age<=150),
    PRIMARY KEY(actor_id),
    CONSTRAINT is_unique UNIQUE(actor_id),
    CONSTRAINT actor_id_checker CHECK(actor_id>0 and actor_id<=9999999)
)
```

Comment: Why are you missing semi colon after create Casts and create Actor ?

Comment: sorry my bad :/ added now

Comment: is INT(4) works in oracle ?

Comment: @praveen seems like it isnt :D thanks to mr mt0 i've learn that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors are:

- `INT` or `NUMBER(4,0)` and not `INT(4)`
- You cannot have a unique key and a primary key on the same column.
- An inline foreign key just need the `REFERENCES` keyword and does not need `FOREIGN KEY`.

Other issues:

- You probably don't want actor name/surname as fixed-length `CHAR` strings and want to us variable-length `VARCHAR2`.
- You probably want gender to be a code from a fixed list (which can be as long or as short as you find appropriate to describe the actors) rather than as a string.
- You probably don't want to have an `AGE` column as that will be out of date as soon as the first birthday of an actor occurs; instead have a `DATE_OF_BIRTH` column that is a `DATE` data type and then you can calculate the age as and when necessary.
- Using the table name as a prefix for every column is a waste of key strokes; you would be better to just name the columns for what they are without the prefix. Similar with `fk` as a suffix.
- If you are using a `NUMBER(7,0)` for `id` values then you don't need to check that it is less than or equal to 9999999 as it is impossible to be a greater value; however, you can have zero or negative values so the check constraint for the lower bound may still be valid.
- If you are using Oracle 12c or later then you should probably be using an `IDENTITY` column for the `id` values unless you are taking the `id` values from a 3rd party.

```sql
CREATE TABLE Movie (
    id       NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL,
    name     varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    director varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    year     NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ,
    duration NUMBER(3,0),
    language varchar2(15) ,
    rating   number(4,2) , 
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT movie_id_checker CHECK(id>0)
);

CREATE TABLE Casts (
    movie_id INT REFERENCES Movie(id) ,
    id       NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL, 
    fullname varchar2(50) NOT NULL ,
    role     varchar2(50) ,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT cast_id_checker CHECK(id>0)
);

CREATE TABLE Actor (
    cast_id       NUMBER(7,0) REFERENCES Casts(id) ,
    id            NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL,
    name          VARCHAR2(30) ,
    surname       VARCHAR2(25) ,
    gender        CHAR(1)
                  CHECK ( gender IN ( 'M', 'F', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ) ),
    date_of_birth DATE
                  CONSTRAINT real_age_check CHECK(date_of_birth >= DATE '1870-01-01' ),
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT actor_id_checker CHECK(id>0)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a92c9452b503b1e2065af5ba431929f)*

Comment: 1-)cast_id NUMBER(7,0) NOT NULL, 

2-) like in mysql Primary Key = Unique Key + Not Null 

3-) cast_id_fk NUMBER(7,0) REFERENCES Casts(cast_id) , like that?

Comment: note: thank you so much mate it finally works and seems like yes like in mysql Primary Key = Unique Key + Not Null

Comment: i was using table name as a prefix for more understandability but i wont do again, newbie mistake :/

Comment: @blawien You can prefix column names with the table name but it is unnecessary and is just going to add to the amount that you have to type; however, if it helps you to get your code to be correct and make fewer mistakes then the extra typing has value to you. So, prefixing the table name is not wrong and you can ignore that advice .... but its not to everyone's taste (which is why I added that comment).